# Oracle Sql multiple row filtering

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables and i want to filter one table based on another one.
1 table gives me file numbers and the other gives multiple statuses per file.
For example:

```
File No   Status
12345     U-APP
12345     U-FCL
12345     ACT
123456    ACT
123456   CLSOE
```

My goal is that files with certain staus will be totally disapperaed.
I tried the following:

```
Select File_no from my table
Where File status not in ('U-APP', 'U-FCL')
```

I get the following:

```
File No   Status
12345     ACT
123456    ACT
123456   CLSOE
```

my goal is that file 12345 will disappear after filtering...

thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select File_no,Status from mytable where File_no not in (Select File_no from my table
Where File status in ('U-APP', 'U-FCL'))
```